# For future releases, here's a good question to refer to

Tags: discussion

Questions about future/in-development releases target a moving-target and are generally off topic (best practice), but if you come across any, this is a good question to point to in a comment when you close such questions:

[Can I install release 0.4 loki?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/311/242)